# Gparted can't resize Ubuntu. Want to resize it so that I can install Windows

Tags: gparted

I want to resize this part:

[image: want to resize this part]

[image]

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to resize this and give an empty memory so that I can install Windows 10.

However, I can't resize it and don't know why.

Comment: You'll note LOCK symbols on two partitions, those partitions are mounted or *in-use* so cannot be re-sized until after they are umounted. It's easiest to re-size partitions from live media (eg. Ubuntu install media) as then they aren't being used.

Answer (score 1):

At first it is dangerous resize system partitions. I also did it recently and worked without problems...so first backup your data...

1. Download for example ubuntu iso file and create a bootable live usb stick for example with unetbootin or any other software. (In my case it did not work with some usb sticks so try a different one if it doesn't work with the first one)
2. Boot into the live system with the stick and open gparted or any other partition manager.
3. Resize the partition (keep in mind the leave some extra space because you maybe need it in the future

That should do the trick....worked greatly in my case (dualboot UbuntuStudio and Kubuntu).